# How to do intent that open specific file type in a specific location?

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent

I'm trying to open a specific xlsx file in a specific location via some intent but I don't know how to do it.
I have tried to do something like that:

```
private void DrawNotfication() {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT,Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "file.xlsx")));
    PendingIntent ped= PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);


    Notification notification= new Notification.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("file download comlete")
            .setContentIntent(ped).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .build();
    mNotificationManager.notify(0,notification);

}
```

Someone can help me with the syntax?

Comment: By "open", do you mean "view"?

Comment: I mean to open it in the Excel application

Answer (score 0):

> I mean to open it in the Excel application

Presumably, Excel supports `ACTION_VIEW` for this. Replace `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` with `ACTION_VIEW` in your `Intent` constructor. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is for displaying what amounts to the file-open dialog you may be used to from other platforms.

Also note that `Uri.fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0+, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 24 or higher. You will need to use `FileProvider` or something similar, so you can have a `Uri` with a `content` scheme instead of a `file` scheme.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said about the uri.. Actually I don't know how intent work so I don't know what is this uri.. can you write for me the specific syntex that I need?

Comment: @moshe.sasson See [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#sharing-files) and [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed) for more about the Android 7.0+ ban on the `file` scheme.

Comment: I am designing my project for lower versions of android.. Do you know what the syntax I need to write to do this Intent for versions like jellybean?

Comment: @moshesasson: `ACTION_VIEW` has been around since API Level 1.

Comment: `Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "file.xlsx")));`

this is what I need to write?

Comment: @moshesasson: If that is where the file is, then yes.

Comment: I did what you wrote but its open as PDF insted as excel file in the excel app.. How can I fix it?

Comment: @moshesasson: Contact Microsoft for support on integrating with their Excel app, I guess.